# A simple cryptography exercise on $k-n$ secret sharing algorithm

Tags: modular-arithmetic, systems-of-equations

I have a doubt about an exercise.

Suppose we are operating in $Z_{11}$. In a scheme $(2,3)$ where $k=2$ and $n=3$. The secret is $7$.

If I choose $a_1=2$ then $f(x)=2x+7$.

So the participant number one $(p_1)$ share value will be $2*1+7 \bmod 11$, so $p_1=9$.

Moreover, $p_2=11 \bmod 11=0$ and $p_3=13 \bmod 11=2$.

So, if $k$ partecipants want to know the secret, supposing I choose $p_1$ and $p_3$ we should resolve the follwing system:

$$9=a_1+S\\
2=3\cdot a_1+S$$

I tried solving it using substitution method but the result I obtain for $S$ is different from $7$.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).